# BasePage in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i want to create a base class page that has all the *scripts*, *link*, and *icon* in it and i have this so far

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace VGD.Client
{
    public class BasePage : Page
    {
        public new string Title { get; set; }

        protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
        {
            Controls.Add(ParseControl("<!DOCTYPE html>"));
            Controls.Add(ParseControl("<html lang='en'>"));

            Controls.Add(ParseControl(head()));
            Controls.Add(ParseControl(upperBody()));

            base.FrameworkInitialize();
        }

        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            Controls.Add(ParseControl(lowerBody()));

            base.OnPreRender(e);
        }

        private string head()
        {
             string _retVal = @"<head id='Head1' runat='server'>                                    
                                    <title>" + Title + @"</title>                                    
                                </head>";

            return _retVal;
        }

        private string upperBody()
        {
            string _retVal = @"<body>
                                <form runat='server'>";

            return _retVal;
        }

        private string lowerBody()
        {
            string _retVal = @"</form>
                            </body>
                        </html>";

            return _retVal;
        }
    }
}
```

but upon the initialize, it throws an error that **Unexpected end of file looking for `</form>` tag.**

i separated the `upperBody()` and `lowerBody()` so that the content of `Home.aspx` will be added in between the `upperBody()` and `lowerBody()` upon creating the page.

any help please.

Comment: `ParseControl` can't be used for incomplete control markup, which is why it dies - the rest of the markup (the closing tags, i.e. `</form>`) are not provided. You can create the control (from valid markup) and then `Add` to its children collection .. but I'm sure there is a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: Use a Master Page for this.

Comment: i can use master page but i want to code it in code behind and baseclass

Comment: What's stopping you from using codebehind?

Comment: This has disaster written all over it.  Please don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
Page.Header.Controls.Add(Tag("script", _sb.ToString(),
                 new PnAAttribute("type", "text/javascript")));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what you used to have to do before master pages existed.

Use a master page and you can still add whatever custom logic you want in the code-behind, but still reap the benefits of being able to structure your page with actual HTML, instead of having to write those HTML snippets you had in your example, like this:

```
protected override void FrameworkInitialize()
{
    Controls.Add(ParseControl("<!DOCTYPE html>"));
    Controls.Add(ParseControl("<html lang='en'>"));

    Controls.Add(ParseControl(head()));
    Controls.Add(ParseControl(upperBody()));

    base.FrameworkInitialize();
}
```

No need to re-invent the wheel here.

UPDATE:

To store scripts that are available to the master page and any content pages, then use this:

```
<asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
    <Scripts>
        <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=272931&clcid=0x409 --%>
        <%--Framework Scripts--%>

        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery.ui.combined" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
        <%--Site Scripts--%>

    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Comment: i can use master page but i am trying to create a separate base class library because there's a lot of scripts to reference in every page so to make the work easier, i will create a base class that whenever i create a new page, i just inherit to *BaseSamplePage* and the scripts will be automatically added to the newly created page.

Comment: How about using the `<ScriptManager>` control? See updated answer.